# Как сделать автоматический перенос текста с увеличением высоты элемента списка?

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть список, в котором каждый элемент это `Grid` с двумя строками. Первая фиксированной высоты, и она не очень-то меня интересует. А вторая содержит `Label` или `TextBlock`, еще не знаю, что удобней использовать в этом случае. Так вот, текста в этом блоке может быть разное количество и если его слишком много, то он просто выходит за [границу окна](https://ibb.co/cxwUQd). Мне нужно сделать следующее:
1) Перенос текста с увеличением высоты второй строки `Grid'a`.
2) И чтобы перенос текста автоматически подгонялся под размеры окна. Например, [было](https://ibb.co/mbP5yy) и [стало после увеличения окна](https://ibb.co/dtk65d) и наоборот.
Вот разметка списка:

```
    <ListBox x:Name="ListBox" Grid.Row="0">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Image Grid.Column="0"/>
                            <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Label/>
                                    <Label/>
                                </Grid>
                                <Label x:Name="Text" Content="{Binding TText}" Grid.Row="1"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

Comment: Установите TextWrapping у текстового элемента.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Я уже пробовал сделать вот так: `<TextBlock x:Name="Text" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding TText}" Grid.Row="1"/>`. К сожалению, получаю тот же [Результат](https://ibb.co/ckuxdy).

Comment: Потому что стандартно в ListBox все элементы расположены по левому краю и они не знают тем самым размера самого ListBox (его ширины). Установите самому ListBox `HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"`

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Не помогло

Comment: Значит текст прокручивается через Scroll. Можете и его отключить `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"`. Уж больше нечему тут мешать.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Да, вы правы, большое спасибо

Comment: На здоровье, сделайте тут ответом то, что помогло.